# Set default value for allowMultipleNulls to TRUE

Tags: cakephp

I think I am missing something.

[In CakePHP 4.2 the new option allowMultipleNulls was added](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/validation.html#creating-unique-field-rules). The default value is `FALSE`. Is there a way to set it to `TRUE` for the whole project?

With this option I finally can save `NULL` values in unique fields without any effort.

Currently I have edited the line #39 in `cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Rule/IsUnique.php` and set it to `TRUE` but this is the death penalty as with the next CakePHP update this gets overwritten.

Comment: Make your own rule that extends this and adds that as a default if not otherwise provided?

Comment: @GregSchmidt I was checking the rules but I understood that I have to set up for each table a rule - or am I wrong?

Comment: That's correct. I thought your problem was not that you have to add the rule everywhere, but that you didn't want to have to specify the `allowMultipleNulls` every time you add the rule. So my point was that you're not limited to Cake's rules, so you can make your own rule that does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Currently CakePHP doesn't offer a simple way to set the default value to `TRUE`. I opened a [new issue](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/15734) regarding this and now they are discussing about some principal questions and how to implement it in the most complicated way.

My point of view is that each underlying database engine accepts `NULL` in a unique index but CakePHP is *baking* here something completely strange and different.

In CakePHP 4.x it was removed and in CakePHP 4.2 it was re-introduced again but with the default `FALSE`.

However, as it may take ages until they implement a very simple method to set the default value to `TRUE` I am using the below few lines of code. The point is that the next CakePHP update overrides my modification in their source code and this breaks then my project.

Therefore I check each time in `app_local.php` the current default value of `allowMultipleNulls`  and when it isn't `TRUE` then the project dies with a notification. A *responsible* developer isn't running an update while the business hours and tests after the update the site, so this solution is working for me very reliable without bothering the users. I can live with the very small delay which needs the execution of the code.

```
$voidIsUnique = new \Cake\ORM\Rule\IsUnique( [], [] );
$isUnique     = new ReflectionClass(\Cake\ORM\Rule\IsUnique::class);
$property     = $isUnique->getProperty("_options");
$property->setAccessible(TRUE);
if ( !$property->getValue($voidIsUnique) ["allowMultipleNulls"] ) {

    die('<span style="background-color: black; color: yellow; font-size: 36px;">' .
          'IsUnique::_options ["allowMultipleNulls"] is FALSE. Fix the source code!</span>');

}
$property->setAccessible(FALSE);
```

Once CakePHP team implemented something I will update it here.

Comment: die() is the worst idea possible. Throwing exception will ensure it is logged (in logs) and not show this detail to the users of the page.

Comment: @mark Not, it isn't. I explained why. It is 100% perfect for the case.